# Apache htaccess Redirect - Why does my double quoted request string act find and replace?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

```
Redirect 302 "/blog" /
```

I would expect this rule to take requests from `/blog` to `/` and `/blog/stuff` to `/`; instead of `/blog/stuff` to `//stuff`

The behavior of going from `/blog/stuff` to `//stuff` is what I would expect from an unclosed regex

what is going on?
I thought Redirect was supposed to redirect to a different URL, not substitute the match with the target string.

Why doesn't one directive do one thing?

Answer (score 1):

The quote marks do not work as you expect them, in the [`Redirect`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirect) directive. For the syntax:

```
Redirect [status] [URL-path] URL
```

> [...]
>   Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect
>   request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional
>   path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the
>   target URL**.

You're probably looking for the [`RedirectMatch`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirectmatch) directive instead.

```
RedirectMatch 302 /blog.* /
```

---

The quoted pattern/path is just a syntactic sugar, available to enclose paths containing  (spaces).

Comment: doesn't redirect match take regex as the request argument?

Comment: @ahnbizcad Yes, it does. Which is why it'll replace everything `/blog....` with just `/`

Comment: I want it to trigger on `/blog` only. If it has stuff after `/blog`, I don't want it to trigger. And I don't want it to replace, I want it to just go to that relative URL. So would `RedirectMatch 302 ^/blog$` work? I was pretty sure it wasn't working when I tested. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @ahnbizcad Perhaps try a pattern like `^/blog/?$`